# Enable dependency for a vue plugin

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-cli

I have a vue-cli app where I have installed a plugin:

```
npm i vue-mover
```

I have enabled this plugin in main.js

```
import mover from 'vue-mover'
Vue.use(mover)
```

And tried to use this in a component.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="lineasMover">   
        <mover 
            target-id="MyMover"
            :left-items="selectedItems"
            :right-items="unselectedItems"
            title-left="Available Items"
            title-right="Selected Items"
            moved-item-location="top | bottom"
            >
        </mover>
    </div>
</template>
```

When i run my app, I'm getting this error in the browser's console:

```
"Uncaught ReferenceError: Sortable is not defined"
```

the plugin has it's code in a file called vue-mover.js, and this is the faulty code:

```
if (!Sortable) {
    throw new Error('[vue-mover] cannot locate `Sortablejs` dependency.')
}
```

I have installed

```
npm i sortablejs
```

and also the vue version

```
npm i vue-draggable
```

but still get this error in console. I guess I need to enable a global "Sortable" variable that points to SortableJS, so that any plugin can use it, but I can't figure out how to achieve this.

Any ideas??

Comment: Give this a go: `import * as Sortable from "sortablejs"; window.Sortable = Sortable;`

Comment: try `npm i vuedraggable` with no hyphen

Comment: vuedraggable without hyphen made no difference. Where am I supossed to put the window.Sortable line of code? It's a vue-cli application